# Issues with Java Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I meet a problem while using Java Scanner. When I used two nextLine() in the code, and there would be two "\n" in the string entered by me via command line. I did't understand why this happen, please help.

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        int num = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine().trim());
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(input.nextLine().trim().split(" ")));
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beW4s.png)

this is my input:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ1i6.png)

Comment: can you paste your code in the body of this question, as code? I have an idea of why this might be happening, but I want to see all of the code first, not blocked by a debugger window

Comment: yeah, I have updated

Comment: if you first entered 2, then it should wait for more input twice, and print an array with the values you entered after each time you press enter. Did you by any chance press enter twice after the first wait?

Comment: No, I think I only press one enter, you can try this code

Comment: including import statements would be helpful to those who are trying to run the code. Can you include enough code that someone can run it as is?

Comment: yes, I have updated

Comment: I just ran this and it works perfectly, what is the issue? you must be pressing enter twice somewhere. Edit: can confirm this is what happens if you press enter twice, I just tried it.

Comment: I think i only used one enter, but I am not sure what is the problem. What is jdk version you use

Answer (score 2):

This issue only occurs when you run your program in an IDE, and the problem is the way the IDE works. You might want to report it as a probable bug to your IDE vendor. (I can reproduce this issue in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1.)

If you run this from the command line, it works fine.

*UPDATE*

This has been fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.2. It appears to be this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-293951